# Eclipse plugin: How to perform some action when file is opened or closed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am a newbie in Eclipse plugin development.

I want to do some operations(like check its contents for some strings, take backup copy, etc) whenever file is opened or closed in Eclipse editor.(AFAIK not a eclipse RCP application)

After some searches, I came across using command ID

1. org.eclipse.ui.file.import : when file is opened in eclipse text editor
2. org.eclipse.ui.file.close : when file is closed/removed from eclipse text editor

And, this what I tried:

In manifest.mf / extensions -

[image: setting extension for required file handler]

And, inside manifest -> Extensions -> All Extensions -> org.eclipse.ui.handlers

[image: setting handlsers for file import and close]

FileImportHandler file -

```
package com.example.eclipse.handlers;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;



public class FileImportHandler extends AbstractHandler {

@Override
public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("File import called.");
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isHandled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


}
```

But, I am getting following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-11-14 12:40:33.266
!MESSAGE The proxied handler for 'com.example.eclipse.handlers.FileImportHandler' could not be loaded
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in Demo-eclipse-plugin was unable to load class com.example.eclipse.handlers.FileImportHandler.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.loadHandler(HandlerProxy.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ImportResourcesAction.run(ImportResourcesAction.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle Demo-eclipse-plugin (618).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
... 52 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.example.eclipse.Activator.start() of bundle Demo-eclipse-plugin.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
... 64 more
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Your plug-in activator is producing an exception in the `start` method:

```
Exception in com.example.eclipse.Activator.start()
```

what are you doing there?

The handlers for these commands are responsible for showing the import and export dialog which I don't think is what you are trying to do.

You can listen for changes to files using an `IResourceChangeListener`

Comment: Well, I have managed to resolve the issue in 
    Activator.start() and now I am getting it called properly.

But, I don't think its what I am looking for...
Could you please suggest which is proper way of handling file open event, in the similar way we have for save. [org.eclipse.ui.file.save]

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking for. All these commands are for actually displaying the import or open dialogs, they cannot be used to track the dialog being used by another part of Eclipse.

Comment: As mentioned in question, I just want to do some task whenever a file is opened and closed in eclipse text editor.  Could you please provide me any pointer regarding this.

Comment: Well, just now I came across something called ActionFactory.CLOSE and its other methods like CLOSE_ALL, CLOSE_OTHERS [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.ui/workbench/3.6.1/org/eclipse/ui/actions/ActionFactory.java#ActionFactory)  But, couldn't find how to use them for our purpose.

Comment: Again those are the actions to invoke dialogs they cannot be used to track things.

Comment: You can use `IPartListener` to see parts (including editors) being opened. `IResourceChangeListener` will tell you about files being changed.

Comment: Ok thanks, will investigate on IPartListener and IResourceChangeListener.